# Why doesn't Array override the triple equal sign method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, language-design, switch-statement, equality

I've just noticed that Array doesn't override the triple equal sign method `===`, which is sometimes called the case equality method.

```
x = 2

case x
  when [1, 2, 3] then "match"
  else "no match"
end # => "no match"
```

whereas the range operator does:

```
x = 2

case x
  when 1..3 then "match"
  else "no match"
end # => "match"
```

You can do a workaround for arrays, however:

```
x = 2

case x
  when *[1, 2, 3] then "match"
  else "no match"
end # => "match"
```

Is it known why this is the case?

Is it because it's more likely for `x` to be an actual array than a range, and array overriding `===` would mean that ordinary equality would not be a match?

```
# This is ok, because x being 1..3 is a very unlikely event
# But if this behavior occurred with arrays, chaos would ensue?
x = 1..3

case x
  when 1..3 then "match"
  else "no match"
end # => "no match"
```

Comment: Your intuition matches mine. I can't think of a lot of scenarios where you'd want to pass a Range to a `case` expression to have it matched against other Ranges, but I can think of several where you'd pass an Array to see if it matched another array exactly.

Comment: You'll probably have to ask core for a definitive answer. My guess is that arrays don't behave like that *because* ranges do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's [in the specification](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/case_spec.rb).

```
it "treats a literal array as its own when argument, rather than a list of arguments"
```

The spec [was added](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/349eea175bd8ba0d26dc6d7577cb1b16e83eb9fd/language/case_spec.rb) February 3, 2009 by [Charles Nutter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152946/charles-oliver-nutter) ([@headius](https://twitter.com/#!/headius)). Since this answer's probably not what you're looking for, why don't you ask him?

To take a wild and completely uninformed stab in the dark, it seems to me that you might have hit upon the answer by using [a splat](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/splat_spec.rb) in your question. Since the functionality is available by design, why duplicate when doing so would remove the ability to test Array equality? As [Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179125/jordan) points out above, situations exist where this is useful.

---

Future readers should note that unless the array in question is already instantiated, using an array at all is not necessary to match on multiple expressions:

```
x = 2

case x
  when 1, 2, 3 then "match"
  else "no match"
end # => "match"
```