# Using a class object in case statement

Tags: ruby, class, switch-statement

What is the best way to use a class object in case statement? Suppose I have `a` which is an instance of the `Class` class. I want to match it against different classes. If I do

```
case a
when String then ...
when Fixnum then ...
end
```

this will not give the intended result because even if `a == String` for example, `a === String` is not true. What is the clever way to do this?

Comment: same topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908380/ruby-class-types-and-case-statements)

Comment: @selman The question you linked is irrelevant. The `item` in that example is not a class instance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wouldn't use `to_s`, because `"String".to_s` would be `"String"`, so maybe I'd do

```
case
when a == String then ...
when a == Fixnum then ...
end
```

or

```
a = String

case [a]
when [String] then puts "String"
when [Array] then puts "Array"
end
```

Comment: I don't get why the `[]` trick works. It pretty much does exactly what I want it to. Could you give any pointers?

Comment: @wrtsprt because Array doesn't override the Case Equality operator :) So this is the same as `[String] == [String]` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734245/why-doesnt-array-override-the-triple-equal-sign-method-in-ruby

Answer (score 11):

The problem with using something like this:

```
case a.to_s
when "String" then ...
when "Fixnum" then ...
end
```

is that it completely misses subclasses so you can get something that is a String but is missed by your first branch. Also, `name` would be a better choice than `to_s` since semantically, you're testing the class's name rather than its string representation; the result may be the same but `case a.name` would be clearer.

If you want to use a `case` and deal with subclassing then you could use [`Module#<=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-3C-3D) like this:

```
case
when a <= String then ...
when a <= Fixnum then ...
end
```

Yes, you have to repeat `a` in each `when` but that's just how `case` works.

Answer (score -1):

My temporary answer is to use `to_s`, but am not sure if this is the best that can be done. Waiting for better answers.

```
case a.to_s
when "String" then ...
when "Fixnum" then ...
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Because

```
Array === Array # return false
```

and "case when" means "===", so you meet the problem.