# Why are Ruby cases not working with classes?

Tags: ruby, string, class, switch-statement

```
case "Hello".class
  when Integer
      print "A"
  when String
      print "B"
  else
      print "C"
end
```

Why do I get "C"? Was expecting "B" since if you evaluate `"String".class` you do get `String`.

Comment: Lots of votes for closing this! I'm sorry :(..., but why is this a bad question? I just found an odd behavior in Ruby I could not understand...

Comment: Why would you expect `B`? `"Hello".class` is obviously a `Class` and neither an `Integer` nor a `String`, so `C` is the only sensible answer here.

Comment: @JörgWMittag perhaps the OP didn't know that case statements use `===` rather than `==`.

Comment: A related (but not identical) question you (Omega) may be interested in is http://stackoverflow.com/q/9537895/38765

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Oh I don't know - perhaps I'm too new to Ruby and didn't know that the case statement used ===? You may find it obvious, which is great, but I don't, thanks.

Comment: It's completely irrelevant what `case` desugars into. My question is why the OP thinks that the `#class` method would return anything other than a `Class`. My guess is that there is some shitty tutorial out there which teaches this, and I would like to know which tutorial that is, so that I can warn people about it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: No tutorial - I just made a wrong assumption - you see, I supposed that `#class` would throw me a `String`, from where the case statement would compare `String == String`. But no, I was simply wrong because I didn't understand it well. That's all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Confusingly, Ruby's `case` statement uses [`===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) to compare each case to the subject.  [`Class#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) tests for instances of that class, but not the class itself:

```
> Fixnum === Integer
false
> Fixnum === 1
true
```

The `case` behavior that Ruby is trying to promote is:

```
case "Hello"
  when Integer
    puts "A"
  when String
    puts "B"
  else
    puts "C"
end
```