# Triple equals versions of Enumerable functions

Tags: ruby

The Ruby triple equals `===` is nice in some cases, but it gets limited use in the standard library of functions, especially on Enumerables. Are there common idioms for achieving things like a triple equals `member?` function without having to write a custom one or include some gem that may implement such functions?

The only function I'm aware of like this is `grep`, which is like a specialized `select` for triple equals.

I ask because it'd be nice to do things you might do in case statements with Enumerable functions, like writing:

```
[/this/, /that/].member? "what"
```

or

```
[MyClass, MyOtherClass].member? some_object
```

Comment: are you trying to check if `some_object` is an object of which classes from the array ?

Comment: You can do `[MyClass, MyOtherClass].any? { |klass| klass === some_object }` also..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Array override the triple equal sign method in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734245/why-doesnt-array-override-the-triple-equal-sign-method-in-ruby)

Comment: @ArupRakshit that's basically how i have it solved right now, although in my case i'm using `detect` instead of `any?` because i had some use for knowing which thing matched. this works, but i didn't know if this is common or if there is something better

Comment: @GGordonWorleyIII The one you are looking for, I got it. But as far as I know, there is no such a direct method to solve your one. I meant to say, what you are looking for, exact same method, not available. But as you are using `detect`, I would tell you then, to use `[MyClass, MyOtherClass] & some_object.class.ancestors`.. :) Still a workaround :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813516/triple-equals-versions-of-enumerable-functions?noredirect=1#comment36637407_23813516) of mine -

Looking at your need, I can suggest you one way to meet the need, which you are looking for:

```
[MyClass, MyOtherClass] & some_object.class.ancestors
```

Although it is still an wrokaround using [*Array Intersection*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-26).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
case "what"; when /this/, /that/
  ...
end

case some_object; when MyClass, MyOtherClass
  ...
end
```